# Unable to save the record

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

Competitor object has been designed using Visualforce.

Facing Problem:when i click on save button,the record was not saved ,it is remaining on the same page.Here is my work.

Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Competitor__c" extensions="ctrlCompetitor" language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.lang}" action="{!init}" >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"/>  
    <apex:sectionheader title="{!$ObjectType.Competitor__c.label} Edit" subtitle="{!IF(ISNULL(Competitor__c.name), 'New Competitor',Competitor__c.name)}"/>

    <script>    
 function SubmitOnClick (objSubmitBtn) {
    objSubmitBtn.disabled = true;
    objSubmitBtn.value = 'Submitting...';
    doSubmit();
    }
    function chngPrimComp(cmp,val){        
        var c; 
        var flag=0;
        if(cmp.checked==false && flag!=0){            
            alert('{!$Label.msgCantUnchk}');
            cmp.checked=true;
            flag++;
        } 
        if(cmp.checked==true && flag==0){              
            ctrlCompetitor.checkFirstPrimaryComp('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL}',function(result, event){
                if(event.status){            
                    if(result=='false'){                    
                    c=confirm('{!$Label.msgPrmryCompCnfrm}');
                        if(c==true){
                        flag++;                               
                            ctrlCompetitor.checkPrimaryComp('{!$CurrentPage.parameters.retURL}',function(result, event){
                                if(event.status){}
                                if(event.exception){}
                            });
                        }
                        else if(c==false){
                        cmp.checked=false;
                        }
                    }
                }   
            });
        }        
    }
    </script>

    <apex:form >   
        <apex:pageblock mode="edit"  title="{!$ObjectType.Competitor__c.label} Edit" >
     <apex:PageMessages />
            <apex:pageblockbuttons > 

                <apex:commandButton value="Save"      id="save" onclick="SubmitOnClick(this);"/>   

<apex:actionFunction name="doSubmit" action="{!Save}" />
                <apex:commandbutton value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"/>
            </apex:pageblockbuttons>
            <apex:outputpanel >
                <apex:pageblocksection title="Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                        <apex:inputfield id="oppid" value="{!Competitor__c.Opportunity__c}" required="true"/>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Amount__c}" required="false"/>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Competitor_Name__c}" required="true"/>                 
                        <apex:inputfield id="chkbox" value="{!Competitor__c.Primary_Competitor__c}" required="false" onchange="chngPrimComp(this,this.value);" />                                               
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Competitor_Machine__c}" required="false"/>                                                
                        <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Competitor_Machine_Description__c}" required="false"/>
             <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                    <apex:pageblocksection title="Competitor Strengths / Weaknesses" showheader="true" columns="2">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Competitors_Strength__c}" required="false"/>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Competitors_Weakness__c}" required="false"/>
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Competitive_Situation__c}" required="false"/>
         <apex:pageblocksectionitem />
                </apex:pageblocksection>
                        <apex:pageblocksection title="System Information" showheader="true" columns="2">
                        <apex:inputfield value="{!Competitor__c.Name}" required="true"/>                        
                 </apex:pageblocksection>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:pageblock>       
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

====================================================================
Controller:

```
public with sharing class ctrlCompetitor { 


    public static Integer flag=0; 

 public Competitor__c cc{get;set;} 
 public String customerId{get;set;}
    public Competitor__c cc1=new Competitor__c(); 
    public List<Competitor__c> listComptr=new List<Competitor__c>();  
    public ctrlCompetitor(){}

    //extension invoked to pre-populate the Name parameter
    public ctrlCompetitor(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {  

     try{
       cc=new Competitor__c();      
       cc = (Competitor__c)stdController.getRecord(); 
       if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')!=null)
         cc.Name=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name'); 
     }
     catch(Exception e){System.debug(e.getMessage());}
    }

   //cache all the primary competitors for the particular opportunity
   public void init(){    

    listComptr=[SELECT Id,Name,Primary_Competitor__c from Competitor__c where 
                                 Opportunity__r.Id =:ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16) AND Primary_Competitor__c=true]; 
                                 system.debug('the value of string:' +listComptr)    ;
   }

   //method to uncheck the primary competitor for other competitor records     
   @RemoteAction
   public static void checkPrimaryComp(String oppId){ 

    Map<Id,Competitor__c> compMap=new Map<Id,Competitor__c>([SELECT Id,Name,Primary_Competitor__c from Competitor__c where Opportunity__r.Id =: 
                                         oppId.substring(1,16)]);     
     for(Competitor__c comp : compMap.values()){         
        comp.Primary_Competitor__c=false;}       
     update compMap.values();      
   }

   //invoked to check for the first primary competitor
   @RemoteAction
   public static String checkFirstPrimaryComp(String oppId){
   List<Competitor__c> listTemp=[SELECT Id,Name,Primary_Competitor__c from Competitor__c where 
                                 Opportunity__r.Id =:oppId.substring(1,16) AND Primary_Competitor__c=true];
       if(listTemp.size()==0){return 'true';}
       else{return 'false';}   

   }

   //method invoked on update of Competitor records
   public void onUpdatePrimaryComp(){

   try{
     if(Trigger.IsUpdate && !Trigger.IsInsert && flag==0){
     flag++;
     SET<Id> oppIds=new SET<Id>();          
     for(Sobject sobj: Trigger.new){
        Competitor__c cc1=(Competitor__c)sobj;
        oppIds.add(cc1.Opportunity__c);             
     }       
     List<Competitor__c> listTemp=[SELECT Id,Name,Primary_Competitor__c,Competitor_Machine__c,Competitor_Machine_Description__c,Opportunity__r.Id from Competitor__c where Opportunity__r.Id in : oppIds AND
                               Primary_Competitor__c=true] ;        
     if(listTemp.size()!=0){
         for(Sobject sobj: Trigger.new){
             Competitor__c cc1=(Competitor__c)sobj;

             if(cc1.Primary_Competitor__c==true){
                 for(Integer i=0;i<listTemp.size();i++){
                     if(listTemp.get(i).Opportunity__r.Id == cc1.Opportunity__c){
                       listTemp.get(i).Primary_Competitor__c=false;}
                 }
             }
          } 

       update listTemp;}     
     }}
     catch(Exception e){


     System.debug('==Exception Message==='+e.getMessage());}
   }

    //method invoked to save and return to the original Opportunity record Page

    public PageReference Save(){

 PageReference pr;
    try{
   if (cc.id==null)
    // if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')!=null)
      {

      insert cc;

       pr = new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16));

      }
      else 
   {   update cc;
  pr = new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16));
  }
    }
       catch(DMLException e){

       ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR, e.getdmlMessage(0) );
ApexPages.addMessage(msg);


     }   

      return pr;
      //new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16));
    }

    //method is invoked on click of CANCEL button
    public PageReference Cancel(){
    try{
    if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')==null){
        if(listComptr.get(0).primary_Competitor__c==false){
            listComptr.get(0).primary_Competitor__c=true;
        }
    }
      update listComptr;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.debug('==Exception Message==='+e.getMessage());
    }
     return new PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16));

    }

  }
```

=========================================================================================

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separate insert and update. You can use `upsert` and try with `setRedirect(true)`:

```
          try
          {
               upsert cc;
               pr = new  PageReference('/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('retURL').substring(1,16));
               pr.setRedirect(true);     
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {
               ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(Apexpages.Severity.ERROR, e.Message() );
               ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
               return null;
          }
```

Also check your `substring` method you are using. Can you make sure that substring(1,16) will work correct? If an retURL is `'apex/somePageHaving16Letters'` then this will be returned as `'pex/somePageHavi'` leaving the first letter and all after index 16. And if string size is less than 16, it will throw error

Also logic may cause error if there is no `retURL` param.

Comment: @regeal, yup u  right in substring returl dosen't capturing id

Comment: @user4902 for now you must use `str.substring(startpoint)` only. In addition it will be more safe that if retURL has working string which doesn't require use of substring and append etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the default save method?  You don't seem to be doing anything special in your save method, so why bother overriding it?

Also, is there a 'retURL' and 'saveURL' in the parameters?  Did it even hit your save method, or is there something failing in your javascript that you call before the save method?  The javascript doesn't seem to be adding anything useful to your save method.  I would just remove that actionFunction and simply use the standard Save method called from your apex:commandButton.

To me, I don't see your additional logic doing anything useful unless there is something I'm missing.